# "Expected expression" error in C language

Tags: c, syntax, expression, constants

So I'm making this C program to calculate the cost depending of the type of transport. The code you're seeing here is a really small postion of my actual code, but it's pretty much similar to the one I actually have (I had to change the terms to English to ease the understanding).

Also, I know how to code correctly in Java, and since C looks a lot like Java, I guess my logic here is ok. So I'm thinking I'm just missing some syntax error here since I'm new in the C language.

Where I put "Expected expression" is where I get the error at.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MONTANT_METRO_BUS = 8.00
#define MONTANT_OMNIBUS = 9.00;
#define MONTANT_TRAIN_RAPIDE = 10.00;
#define MONTANT_INTEGRE = 12.00;
#define MONTANT_ORANGE_CARD = 65.00;  

#define CODE_METRO_BUS 'm'
#define CODE_OMNIBUS 'o'
#define CODE_RAPIDE 'r'
#define CODE_INTEGRE 'i'
#define CODE_CARTE_ORANGE 'c'

void lireTransport();

char codeTransport;
double costTransport;

int main {
    lireTransport();
}

void lireTransport() {
    printf("Enter transport code: ");
    scanf("%c",&codeTransport);
    while (codeTransport != CODE_METRO_BUS &&
            codeTransport != CODE_OMNIBUS &&
            codeTransport != CODE_RAPIDE &&
            codeTransport != CODE_INTEGRE &&
            codeTransport != CODE_CARTE_ORANGE){
        printf("Error! Retry: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&codeTransport);
    }

    switch (codeTransport) {
        case CODE_METRO_BUS:    costTransport = COST_METRO_BUS;  //Expected expression
                                break;
        case CODE_OMNIBUS:      costTransport = COST_OMNIBUS;  //Expected expression
                                break;
        case CODE_RAPIDE:       costTransport = COST_TRAIN_RAPIDE; //Expected expression
                                break;
        case CODE_INTEGRE:      costTransport = COST_INTEGRE; //Expected expression
                                break;
        case CODE_CARTE_ORANGE: costTransport = MONTANT_ORANGE_CARD; //Expected expression
                                break;
    }
}
```

But when I replace the constants by direct values, no error occure

```
switch (codeTransport) {
            case CODE_METRO_BUS:    costTransport = 1.25;
                                    break;
            case CODE_OMNIBUS:      costTransport = 2.50;
                                    break;
            case CODE_RAPIDE:       costTransport = 3.75;
                                    break;
        case CODE_INTEGRE:          costTransport = 4.2;
                                    break;
        case CODE_CARTE_ORANGE:     costTransport = 5.25
                                    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side point: `int main` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: `case CODE_METRO_BUS:    costTransport = COST_METRO_BUS; ` Where do you define COST_METRO_BUS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
#define MONTANT_TRAIN_RAPIDE = 10.00;
```

to

```
#define MONTANT_TRAIN_RAPIDE 10.00
```

etc.

---

The `#define` is part of the preprocessor which is kind a primitive precompiler that runs before the C proper. The precompiler operates on text (tokens really) and does simple replacements.

When you do

```
#define MONTANT_TRAIN_RAPIDE 10.00
```

future mentions of MONTANT_TRAIN_RAPIDE will get replaced by `10.00`.

With `#define MONTANT_TRAIN_RAPIDE = 10.00;`, the replacement would be `= 10.00;`, which would yield syntactically invalid C source (you'd have the `=` token where the compiler would expect an expression: hence the "expression expected" error).

POSIX-compliant compilers will let you see the textual form of the results of the preprocessing if you run them with `-E`.

I.e.:

```
gcc -E your_source.c
```

will show you the results of your macro expansions, letting you really see the erroneous:

```
costTransport = = 10.00;;
```

where you had

```
costTransport = COST_TRAIN_RAPIDE;
```

etc.

Comment: Ah, silly me. I totally didn't see this error for some reasons. Thanks

Comment: @MathieuGouin You're welcome. I made that mistake quite recently and I'm not new to C. :D If you don't mind a piece of advice: you'll have a much easier time finding these errors if you piece the program together piece by piece instead of trying to compile a big chunk of new code at once.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. But how do you do it exactly? DO you just copy a block (or method?) and just paste it in an online compiler, or just another software?

Comment: @MathieuGouin Like start with a single-case switch in the function, compile. Then add the other cases, compile, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A macro created with `#define` does a direct substitution into the source code.  It is not a variable that gets assigned to.  So given this:

```
#define MONTANT_OMNIBUS = 9.00;
```

Then this:

```
case CODE_OMNIBUS:      costTransport = COST_OMNIBUS;  //Expected expression
```

Becomes:

```
case = 9.00;:      costTransport = = 9.00;;  //Expected expression
```

Get rid of the `=` and the `;` so the symbol is replaced with just the value:

```
#define MONTANT_OMNIBUS 9.00
```